# How can i put default top menu item inside custom header in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento 2. i am facing a problem with default top-menu block. I create a custom header and i want to move top-menu block in my custom header. But not get success
Code:

Custom header file :

```
<div class="header">  <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?> 
        <div class="container">
             <div class="nav-top">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("catalogTopnav"); ?> 
             </div>
</div>
</div>
```

layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
              name="custom_header" as="custom_header" 
              template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml"  before="-" /></referenceContainer>    
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="custom_header" after="logo" />
```

Please help me any one how to print top menu item in my custom header. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you are moving the `catalog.topnav` element in your layout file, but are asking for the `catalogTopnav` element in your template file. The easiest solution is to change the code as followed.

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("catalog.topnav"); ?>` in your template file